# EXC_BREAKPOINT in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I set up a `var tagTextField: UITextField` in the a set up method. Later when I call a method where I want to do something with this `var tagTextField: UITextField`, namely:

```
var pos1 = tagTextField.positionFromPosition(tagTextField.beginningOfDocument, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.Right, offset: 0)
```

I get the following Error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1000e4280)
```

I tried to just see if the `var tagTextField: UITextField == nil`, but then I get the same Error. Any suggestions why this is? If you need more code, let me know.

Thanks in advance

edit:

here is the error. no breakpoint 
[image]

Comment: I didn't set a breakpoint. Thats why I don't get it...

Comment: If I comment out all the places where i use tagTextField, everything works fine. But tagTextField is 100% not nil. So where could be the error?

Comment: This is a user-set breakpoint. Not any sort of error.

Comment: and how do i get this user-set breakpoint away? usually there is a blue bar at the left side where i can deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

You set a breakpoint on Xcode (probably by mistake when trying to access to a specific line).
Breakpoints are represented by blue tabs and allow you to stop the execution of your code to check some variable states for instance. Just click on it again to deactivate it (it will turn light blue).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've set some sort of user-breakpoint.

All user-set breakpoints show up in the Breakpoint Navigator:

[image]

If your Xcode doesn't say "No Breakpoints" here, you have breakpoints.  Good news is, you can manage all your breakpoints from this tab.  You can delete them, or create new ones.

Click the plus sign at the bottom lets you add different sorts of breakpoints here.

Comment: It says No Breakpoints. So I guess I don't have any breakpoints. :(